# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on initializing bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm developing a Spring Batch based application and after I've introduced ShutdownHook to stop my jobs gracefully (guided by instructions from https://numberformat.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/shutting-down-spring-batch-jobs-gracefully/), I started to get some weird exception everytime the hook gets executed (i.e. everytime program terminates)

```
`Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:370)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:296)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:337)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:252)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b81f4553.stop(<generated>)
at com.tsi.tesb.autodeploy.proto.batch.ProcessShutdownListener$1.run(ProcessShutdownListener.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dbf00617.setBeanFactory(<generated>)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$EnhancedConfigurationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:442)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
... 22 more`
```

After search for something similar, I've tried to set the same and fresh versions of Spring components in POM, but it didn't help. Debugging through the Spring code I've found out that the SimpleBatchConfiguration bean is being instantiated again as shutdown hook gets executed and it has **cglib$callback 0** set to null, which probably is the root of the problem  - but unfortunately I cannot understand why is that so and I'm lost in which direction to dig further.

Could it be some Spring bug or am I'm doing something wrong here?

My POM:

```
`<!-- cut for clarity -->

<!-- 
============================================================================
 Dependencies
============================================================================ 
-->
<dependencies>

    <!-- IBM MQ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- IBM PCF (local) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.pcf</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- IBM IIB (local) -->
    <dependency>
        <!-- <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.iib.integration-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0.3</version> -->
        <groupId>com.ibm.broker</groupId>
        <artifactId>IntegrationAPI</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- db2 api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.19.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- sqlite api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jetty + websocket (for IBM Integration API) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>websocket-common</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache commons compress -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- needed to omit BOM in input files -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SSH -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.54</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Samba -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring batch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8.RELEASE</version> <!-- was 3.0.7 -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version> <!-- was 4.0.5 -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AoP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version> <!-- was 2.2 -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring OXM -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-oxm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring JDBC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SLF4J / logpack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SVN -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.pragmatists</groupId>
        <artifactId>JUnitParams</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<!-- cut for clarity  -->`
```

Shutdown hook implementation class:

```
package com.tsi.tesb.autodeploy.proto.batch;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobExecutionNotRunningException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("processShutdownListener")
public class ProcessShutdownListener implements JobExecutionListener{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessShutdownListener.class);

    private JobOperator jobOperator;

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(final JobExecution jobExecution) {

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                try {
                    jobOperator.stop(jobExecution.getId());
                    while(jobExecution.isRunning()) {
                        LOGGER.info("waiting for job to stop...");
                        try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchJobExecutionException e) { // ignore
                } catch (JobExecutionNotRunningException e) { // ignore
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        //do nothing
    }

    public void setJobOperator(JobOperator jobOperator) {
        this.jobOperator = jobOperator;
    }

}
```

Comment: That does look like a version issue. Have you considered using Spring Boot for this? That might make managing the Spring versions simpler.

Comment: I've tried to reconfigure the project using Spring Boot, first I got an error at initializing one of my beans right at the startup; after a bit of POM tweaking I could start the program, but unfortunately I do get the same error at the hook again...